# apache storm missing event detection based on time

Tags: streaming, apache-storm

I want to detect a missing event in a data stream ( e.g. detect a customer request that has not been responded within 1 hour of its reception. )
Here, I want to detect the "Response" event and make an alert.

I tried using tick tuple by setting TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS but it is configured at a bolt level and might come after 15th minute of getting a customer request.

> @Override public Map getComponentConfiguration() {
>
> ```
> Config conf = new Config();
> conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 1800);
> return conf; }
> ```

^ this doesn't work.

Let me know in comments if any other information is required. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: From what you describe I assume you keep the state of which user ID had issued a request at what time in your bolts (or outside store, like Redis) anyway.

In that case, why not define a tick time which is very short, like 5s, and query the state on every tick for expirations?

Answer (score 0):

This might help http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.3/Windowing.html

you can define 5 mins windows and check the status of last window events and alert based on what is received

or create an intermediate bolt which maintains these windows and sends the normal alert tuples(instead of tick tuple) in case of timeouts